# Piecewise orthogonal (Deming) regression

Tags: r, regression, total-least-squares, segmented-regression

I'm trying to calculate a single breakpoint on $x$ from several thousand $(x,y)$ points. Due to the density distribution as per the 2D histogram below, the least squares method is proving unsuitable. An orthogonal regression is a much better fit for the lower $x$-axis, but is it possible to conduct a piecewise orthogonal regression? How could I do this, preferably in R?

[image]

Comment: Why not transform your data?  Take logs of both axes, maybe try something more extreme...

Comment: Thanks, this worked (log transformed both axes). I avoided transformations initially because I thought they would mask the break.